# Can't use REQUEST_URI and HTTP_REFERER together in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I can't seem to make REQUEST_URI and HTTP_REFERER worker together. If someone visits **/rosters** AND it's NOT coming from **XYZ.com** - they should be redirected to /contact.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/rosters
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^!https://example.org/* [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mypagesite.com/contact/ [R=301,L]
```

Each of the two conditions work independently, but never when combined together. I made sure the inbound link doesn't have noreferrer set.

Comment: You don't need a RewriteCond just to check on the URL path, just phrase your RewriteRule pattern accordingly. `RewriteRule ^rosters$ https://mypagesite.com/contact/ [R=301,L]`

Comment: Yeah, but I want www to behave one way compared to non-www.

Comment: Didn't say lose _all_ the RewriteConds. Although checking on the host name might make more sense, than checking on the referrer (depending on how exactly you meant that though.)